# Regular Expressions during Preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have been looking around now for a while, and I have spent a good amount of time with trial and error, and still can't get things right :/

What I am trying to do is take a string like a url:

`www.something.com/something.html?user=1&page=1`

and remove the `"&page=1"` out of the string. This string may have another `&variable` after `"&page=*"`, so I would like it to only remove the `"&page=*"`.

What I have been trying is:
`$url = preg_replace("/&page=\.{*}&?/","",$url);`

so in other words: `"&page=" + anynumber + till end of number or next "&"`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/&page=[^&#]*/', '', $url)
```

This matches `&page=` followed by 0 or more (that's the `*` bit) characters that aren't `&` or `#`. `[...]` stands for a set of characters; `[^...]` inverts the set.

In other words, it will match everything after `&page=` up to the next `&` or `#` (or end of string).

Comment: That worked Thank you!!
Would you mind explaining it to me so I can understand it for the future?

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it! It makes more sense now! Can't believe how off I was!
Thank you!!